# Azure - cannot get "Network Profile"

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

my Admin in Azure with full permissions runs the command to retrieve the network profile ID with deployed Virtual Network and Subnet which we are using but the command always returns the empty response:

```
az network profile list --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --query [0].id --output tsv
```

It has permissions, resourceGroup value is correct what should be the case?
Why it gets empty response? It is really essential for us to retrieve this value.

The output should contain value in this format:

```
/subscriptions/<Subscription ID>/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkProfiles/aci-network-profile-aci-vnet-aci-subnet
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to list them all using the [List All REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networkprofiles/listall)?

Comment: The given command does work for me. Please make sure you're logged into the right account + subscription. Verify it using `az account show`.

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara thanks for answering... 
Admin did the `az account set --subscription "My Demos"` with his Admin account. Did you maybe do anything else?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara how I can retreieve this value? How I can do the GET can you give me example? with Invoke-WebRequest from PowerShell or can you give me example how I can invoke GET method from az cli or powershell? GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkProfiles?api-version=2020-07-01

Comment: You could try it from the browser itself using the [Try It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCDYn.png) button on the API description.

Comment: Yes, `az account set -s <Subscription Name>` should work. Are you able to see the correct Subscription set when you run `az account show`?

Comment: Any further update here?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara checking info from my admin since I am lacking permissions, is it possible not to have network profile despite having the vnet-snet?

Comment: Do you have more questions? Is the reply helpful?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I must specify network profile during the container creation to existing virtual network. Please take a look at "EXAMPLE YAML" https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet you can see that it must be specify during the creation of container.
Your example refers to creation of container group to a new virtual network and after that creation of additional container group - both are not what I need unfortunately.

I have already virtual network, I have 1 container group to deploy and I need to specify network profile during the creation

Comment: After my validation, you can deploy a container in a new VNet or an existing VNet followed by the example. Please check my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could verify if you have deployed ACI in that VNet instead of only a standard VNet. When use [az network profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/profile?view=azure-cli-latest), **Currently, only Azure Container Instances are supported.**

When you first use the `az container create` command to deploy a container group to a subnet (and thus a virtual network), Azure creates a **network profile** for you. You can then use that network profile for future deployments to the subnet.

For example, if you create a container group in a new VNet or an existing VNet referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#example).

```
az container create \
  --name appcontainer \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld \
  --vnet aci-vnet \
  --vnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 \
  --subnet aci-subnet \
  --subnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/24
```

Then you will list the network profile in that resource group.

[image]

### Update

If you want to deploy a container in an existing VNet, you can deploy it like this with `--vnet NAME --subnet NAME | --vnet ID --subnet NAME | --subnet ID`:

```
az container create --name appcontainer --resource-group nancylab --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld --vnet aci-vnet --subnet subnet1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I marked the answer.
So it seems that only after I create initial container using the az create I get network profile based on which later on I can deploy using the YAML definition. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right. with the YAML file, you only can specify the network information with network profile id, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-reference-yaml#containergroupnetworkprofile-object.

Comment: Thanks. For me it is little illogical how they implemented this, but OK...thank you very much for information and all your efforts